# Accessing defined session / variables inside razor view

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

Here is my partial view that is being re-used on some of my views so it's not strongly typed.

```
@if (Session["time"] != null)
{
    MvcApplication6.Models.calendar cl = (MvcApplication6.Models.calendar)Session["time"];
    var year = cl.schoolyear;
    var term = cl.term;
}



<ul class="lispacer">
    <li><a href="@Url.Action("Details", "Management")">View profile</a></li>
    <li><a href="@Url.Action("Search", "Management")">Search Students</a></li>
    <li><a href="@Url.Action("classes", "Management", new { schoolyear =  , term =  })">Manage Subjects</a></li>
    <li><a href="@Url.Action("calendar", "Management")">Set Calendars</a></li>
    </ul>
    <form id="fooForm" action="@Url.Action("Logout", "Management")" method="post">
        <a href="#" id="submit_link" class="button">Log out</a>
    </form>
```

So from here, i have a `session` that stored a class, i want to retrieve it on my razor view but i don't know how.

here is the line of code where i need it:

```
<li><a href="@Url.Action("classes", "Management", new { schoolyear =  , term =  })">Manage Subjects</a></li>
```

How do i access `year` and `term` variable inside my link? i get red lines if i type them directly on my `Url.Action`

Comment: Declare `year` and `term` before you `if` block and set the values inside the `if` block

Comment: oh nvm aaaa thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can declare `year` and `term` variables out of the `if` statement scope, so, you can access them on the page.

```
var year = 0;
var term = ""; 

@if (Session["time"] != null)
{
    MvcApplication6.Models.calendar cl = (MvcApplication6.Models.calendar)Session["time"];
    var year = cl.schoolyear;
    var term = cl.term;
}



<ul class="lispacer">
    <li><a href="@Url.Action("Details", "Management")">View profile</a></li>
    <li><a href="@Url.Action("Search", "Management")">Search Students</a></li>
    <li><a href="@Url.Action("classes", "Management", new { schoolyear =  , term =  })">Manage Subjects</a></li>
    <li><a href="@Url.Action("calendar", "Management")">Set Calendars</a></li>
</ul>
<form id="fooForm" action="@Url.Action("Logout", "Management")" method="post">
    <a href="#" id="submit_link" class="button">Log out</a>
</form>

<li><a href="@Url.Action("classes", "Management", new { schoolyear =  year, term = term })">Manage Subjects</a></li>
```